# c++20 concept check for function being declared const

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to test out the new concepts feature in c++20 and I was wondering if I can create a concept that checks for the existence of a function that is declared const.
I want the check to fail if the function exists with the right type but isn't const. I couldn't find anything relevant here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts

I have this

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept hasToString = requires (T val) {
    { val.toString() } /* const here gives error */ -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};

void f(hasToString auto bar)
{
    std::cout << bar.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the parameter `const`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept hasToString = requires (T const val) {
    { val.toString() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

Concepts check usage patterns, and so if what you want to check is calling a member function on a `const` object, you need to construct that scenario.

---

Note that this depends on what you want to happen if `T` happens to be a reference type. If you want this to work:

```cpp
void f(hasToString auto&& bar)
```

Then `T` might be a reference type, and if you still want it really be `const`, then you need to turn a type like `T&` into `T const`. The long-way of writing that is:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept hasToString = requires (std::remove_reference_t<T> const val) {
    { val.toString() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

But if you do this enough times, you could consider adding an alias template to handle that.

Answer (score 4):

You can always check the expression is well-formed when applied to a const object argument.

```
template <typename T>
concept hasToString = requires (T val) {
    { std::as_const(val).toString() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

or

```
template <typename T>
concept hasToString = requires (T val, T const cval) {
    { cval.toString() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

Adding an extra object parameter is probably more inline with how abstract concept requirements are defined (well, if your requires-expression checks for more than one requirement). You can have as many parameters as you want in the require-expression's parameter list.

Comment: You may want to point out what happens if `T` is a reference type. The first version puts the `const` under it. The second ignores the `const`.

Comment: @HTNW - Barry has a perfectly good answer that touches upon that. And save for but a few exceptions, answer diversity is a strength of SO.